# How to set environment variables that last

Tags: go, environment-variables

I'm trying to set some environment variables on my machine using [Go OS](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Setenv)

```
    err := os.Setenv("DBHOST", dbHostLocal)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("err %v", err)
    }
```

It seems the variable is available to the Go program but once I quite / terminate the Go process the variable is no longer available. I'm wondering if it's possible to set these variables permanently. The reason is that i was looking to create a "setup" file with config files ( db name etc ) for the local and dev environment so that I could switch between without any setup at all... just one time go run setup.go.

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly that you want to set the shell's environment variables from a process you run from the shell?

Comment: That's not how environment variables work. The child process can only inherit from its parent, not vice-versa.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Short: It is not possible. You can't change the environment of your parent process. You can only change your own and pass it to your children.

What you should do is maintain a config file.
There are plenty of go config libs out there: ini, yaml, etc.

If your program changes the config, save it to disk after each change or one in a while or when the process exits.

Answer (score 11):

Whilst not considered possible, if you're building some cli tool that exits you could consider outputting the equivalent shell to STDOUT like: docker-machine eval.

Quick and dirty example:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "reflect"
  "strings"
)

type config struct {
  db_host string
  db_port int
  db_user string
}

func main() {
  c := config{"db.example.com", 3306, "user1"}

  ct := reflect.ValueOf(&c).Elem()
  typeOfC := ct.Type()

  for i := 0; i < ct.NumField(); i++ {
    f := ct.Field(i)
    fmt.Printf("%s=%v\n", strings.ToUpper(typeOfC.Field(i).Name), f)
  }
}

Output:
$ go run env.go
DB_HOST=db.example.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_USER=user1
```

You can then `eval` it on the command line and have access to those variables.

```
$ eval $(go run env.go)
$ echo $DB_HOST
db.example.com
```

Answer (score 3):

The only way to get the behavior you want is to alter the environment of the current shell, and the easiest way is with a simple shell script

```
# setup.sh
export DBHOST="dbhost.url"
export CONFIG_VAR_TWO="testing"
```

and then

```
$ source setup.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible if you write a value to the registry, but for this, your application needs administrator rights

```
func setEnvironment(key string, value string){
   k, err := registry.OpenKey(registry.LOCAL_MACHINE, `SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment`, registry.ALL_ACCESS)
   if err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
   }
   defer k.Close()

   err = k.SetStringValue(key, value)
   if err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
   }
}
```

Comment: This is just for windows though

Answer (score 0):

Or you can write your env variable definition to stdout and evaluate it from the parent process. Say you have this code into `main.go`:

```
fmt.Println("export DBHOST=myhost")
```

Then from your shell (parent process):

```
$ eval $(go run main.go)
echo $DBHOST
myhost
```