# How to pass parameters from command objects

Tags: go

I use the following code which need to pass value from functions `root, value`

```
var cfBuild = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "build",
    Short: "Build",
    Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {


        root, value := Build(target)
    },
    PersistentPostRun: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
   //Here I need to use root, value
   } 
}
```

I can do it by using global variable but is there a nice way to avoid global in this case ?

This is the repo, I didnt find any nice way to do it ...
https://github.com/spf13/cobra

Btw there is option to use [viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper)

like ...

```
Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
    root, value := Build(target)
    viper.Set("root", root)
    viper.Set("value", value)
```

and then get it in the other method...
Is it good direction?

Comment: A relevant issue: [How can I pass context.Context between pre/post-run hooks?](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/issues/563).

Comment: If i understand correctly then this answer is the exact same problem; 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49981932/6376471

Comment: @Zak , well you answer as my question :) using env( with different approach, here is viper in you answer is   terraform.io/docs/state , isnt it similar approach ?if not why?

Comment: `viper.Set(...)` will not persist between executions of the same program. The docs (https://godoc.org/github.com/spf13/viper#Set) talk say that viper will store the value set in its internal register which means that it will be lost after the program ends.

Assuming in your case the program does not exit between `Run` and `PersistentPostRun` then you will be fine using viper. 
If `PersistentPostRun` is executed as another CLI tool execution then the values in `viper.Set(...)` will be lost.

Comment: @Zak - there is some example code for your solution proposal , some oss example for my context ? if yes please provide it as answer, the link to the second question doesnt help much for my case....

Answer (score 0):

you don't need Viper for that.
Just create 2 singletons (variables with global scope in the command file) and you can assign them to your Build function returns.

Example

```
package cmd

var (
    root,
    value string
)

var cfBuild = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "build",
    Short: "Build",
    Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        root, value = Build(target)
    },
    PersistentPostRun: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        fmt.Printf("%s, %s", root, value)
   } 
}
```